# TCP sockets in Comet programming

Tags: comet

A web server opens a temporary port while sending the response to the clients. In the case of comet programming(streaming), if the response from web server is never going to end, does that mean the web server will always keep the temporary port open for infinite period ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the COMET technique:

1. Client sends request to Server - Server sends data (when it has meaningful data to send ;-) - Client receives data - Client closes.
2. Client sends request to Server - Server sends data in "chunk" (*chunked transfer*) keeping the connection open for as long as it can/instructed to.

Answer (score 0):

It will be open until the server or the client closes the connection.